Unable to resolve "../../../../../../../../../../babel/runtime/helpers/objectSpread2"
After creating a new project using expo:
pnpm create expo-app global-tracker --template blank
npx expo install react-native-web react-dom @expo/metro-runtime

When I try to run the project in the browser:  pnpm run start
pressing w:  › Press w │ open web
I get the error:
Web Bundling failed 621ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (29 modules)
Unable to resolve "../../../../../../../../../../babel/runtime/helpers/objectSpread2" 
from "node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/AppRegistry/index.js"

My fresh package.json after running create expo-app:
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.3",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },


Add the library that doesn't resolve to peerDependencies then in root .npmrc add auto-install-peers=true

The scaffolding when using pnpm builds the App.js using the main function with that syntax:
export default function App() {

But it doesn't work for some reason, changing to below syntax works:
const App = () => {
...
}

export default App;

